# Best way to get/structure statical local file system json content from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, localhost

I'm making a simple javascript app that needs to run locally (on a CD without internet) and it's basically a enhanced image gallery. There are a lot of files that need to be "loaded", so I'm putting the files in a json format, like this:

```
{
     number: 338,
     images: 
     [
       {
          picture_path : "path/file.png",
          place : "Brazil",
          metadata : "...",
       },
       {
          ...
       }
     ]
}
```

My question is, how I can get and structure this data? Is there a Jquery getJSON locally method/parser? It seems that I can reparse the json using javascript eval, but how can I get the content?? Also, is there a way to find info on the give structure data, for instance, suppose that I want all pictures from "Brazil".

I was thinking on embedding a php server and reading, but I thought this is too much trouble.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the question regarding reading json directly from disk using jquery, getJSON supports this; from their documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
$.getJSON('data/images.json', function(data) {

    // you asked a question regarding retrieving all images from place === "Brazil"
    // so we'll store said images in this array
    var picturesFromBrazil = new Array();

    // you want to iterate through the array of images, so we're reference them here
    var images = val.images; 


    // iterate through your images array
    $.each(images, function(key, val) {

    // your data, as described, is an array, where each element is a dictionary
    /*
    {
         number: 338,
         images: 
         [
           {
              picture_path : "path/file.png",
              place : "Brazil",
              metadata : "...",
           },
           {
              ...
           }
         ]
    }
    */

    // question: is there a way to find info on the given structure data, for instance,
    // support that I want all pictures from "Brazil"

    if (val.place === "Brazil" && val.picture_path !== undefined) {
        picturesFromBrazil.push(val.picture_path);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with just a CD then why not go one little step further and just assign your JSON-ish data structure to a JavaScript variable and skip the JSON altogether? You could just do this:

```
var IMAGES = {
     number: 338,
     images: 
     [
       {
          picture_path : "path/file.png",
          place : "Brazil",
          metadata : "...",
       },
       {
          ...
       }
     ]
};
```

Then you don't have to parse anything, the browser's JavaScript engine will do the parsing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should cache all the files in different structured json files (all from Brazil ...), as is doesn't matter if you find a function that will achieve what you are seeking, that function will parse all the json content to an array and then output what you need.

My opinion is eighter you save in multiple organised json files and you load only what you need or you save all on a single file but every time you want to show something you have to make an array and then loop in it.